# Wallis' axiom for parallel lines

Tags: geometry

I want to prove, using the typical tools from a Hilbert plane, that the Wallis' axiom implies ($P_{\leq 1}$), where

Wallis' axiom: Given a triangle $\Delta ABC$ and given a line segment $DE$, there exists a similar triangle $\Delta A'B'C'$, having side $A'B' \geq DE$.

$P_{\leq 1}$: For each line $l$ and for each point $P\notin l$, there is at most one line containing $P$ that is parallel to $l$

I have already proved Proclo's axiom is equivalent to $P_{\leq 1}$, but I got no idea how to solve this problem...

Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: Hilbert space? Don't you mean Euclidean plane?

Comment: That's a mistake. It's Hilbert plane, sorry...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a proof on page 153 of Greenberg, which you may be able to access [here.](https://books.google.com/books?id=uCYPZ4nRqy0C&lpg=PP1&pg=PA153#v=onepage&q&f=false)

If you can't access it or wish to fill in the details yourself, here's a proof sketch. Begin in the standard way: given *l* and P, we construct the parallel line *m* incident to P, and let Q be the foot of the perpendicular from P to *l*. Let *n* be any other line through P.

Now, we can pick a point R on *n*, and drop the parallel to PQ, letting S be the foot. Apply Wallis's postulate to the triangle PSR and the line segment PQ. This produces a point T which must lie on *n* and *l*.

Comment: Must point out that the citation only refers to the third edition of Greenberg's book.  Statement and proof are on the page 216 of the fourth edition.